# Como trabalhar com SlideBar do PrimeNg do Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Observem os dois componentes:

[Sidebar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/sidebar)

[Menu - PanelMenu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu)

Primeiro vou mostrar a forma como a aplicação está se comportando, depois vou mostrar o que estou tentando implementar.

O sistema está comportando assim;

Aparece o botão para clicar e aparecer o menu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no menu o botão desaparece e aparece o menu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que preciso fazer é que ao clicar no botão o menu apareça, mas continue mostrando o botão e ao clicar no botão novamente o menu desapareça, mas continuando mostrando o botão

Porém eu não sei como fazer isso porque eu sou novo como programador Angular e preciso de ajuda.

Aqui está meu código:

```
<div class="container">

<p-sidebar [(visible)]="display" >
    <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>
</p-sidebar>

<button type="text" (click)="display = true" pButton icon="fa-external-link-square" label="Show"></button>

</div>
```

Para quem quiser ter acesso ao meu projeto esse é meu repositório;

[REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/wladyband/controle-de-cervejas)

Comment: Se aplicar o **CSS**: `button { z-index: 1; }` não resolve? Caso não funcione, vai aumentando o número, lembrando que o estilo vai atacar todos os botões, então o ideal é definir um `id` ou `class`.

Comment: não resolveu o problema, infelizmente.

Comment: acredito que isso não tem haver com css, você sabe mexer com Angular?